# How would you say 'it is', or 'OK'?

Tags: word-choice

I am a relative beginner to Japanese and I would like to know how to say 'OK' (roughly equivalent to the Mandarin 好的)?

Thanks!

Comment: 大丈夫(だいじょうぶ) ですtranslates as "It is okay". I was able to translate each character individually on www.jisho.org with a general  meaning of good, but could not find the characters combined in Japanese.

Comment: In what situation? (either for "OK" or "好的")

Comment: `How would you say 'it is', or 'OK'?` -> I always thought "(Yes,) it is" was more like **是**的 ((はい、)そうです), and 好的 was more like "good/okay" ((はい、)いいです(よ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just say :"はい". Or "わかりました" roughly equals to 好的 in Mandarin when you want to say you get what the other person was saying.

Comment: "It is." would be "そうですね" or "そうです" or "そう", when you agree with what the other person said. It's like saying "I know, right?" or 'Yeah." in English.